# HTML and CSS3 dropdown responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive

Recently I am working on a website, and although the page overall is fine in terms of responsiveness, the **dropdown** is not working very well.

I've got the dropdown from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp), and when resizing the page (i.e viewing from different display resolutions) all the buttons resize accordingly except the dropdown button.

In screenshot below, as you can see, under 1366x768 resolution, everything is OK:

[image: nav bar in normal conditions]

However, in second screenshot below, let's try zooming in (simulating other display resolution):

[image: nav bar in other conditions]

**Code**:

```css
.meny {
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float: none;
}

.nmbutoni {
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 21% 37%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float: none;
  transition: linear 0.2s;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .nmbutoni {
    padding: 14% 15%;
  }
}


/* Smartphones (portrait & landscape) */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .nmbutoni {
    padding: 18% 37%;
  }
  footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #282828 !important;
    width: 70% !important;
    color: white;
  }
  #googleMap {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
  }
}


/* position of main menu */

.nenmeny {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* dropdown content (default hidden) */

.nenmeny-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 155px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside dropdown menu*/

.nenmeny-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 7% 9%;
  /*12px 16px*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Hover color change */

.nenmeny-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Displaying content on hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nenmeny-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Bgcolor change on dropdown hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nmbutoni {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFB849;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="meny active">Ballina</a>
<a href="lajme.html" class="meny">Lajme</a>
<a href="ekipet.html" class="meny">Ekipet</a>
<a href="sponsor.html" class="meny">Sponzorët</a>
<div class="nenmeny">
  <button class="nmbutoni">Për ne</button>
  <div class="nenmeny-content">
    <a href="rrethparkour.html">Sporti Parkour</a>
    <a href="historia.html">Historia jonë</a>
    <a href="kontakti.html">Kontakti</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to modify padding and other properties of dropdown class, tried either static (in px), or using percentage with no luck.

Comment: If you are being paid to do this, I suggest you use Bootstrap.  http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: How are users going to access content under *nenmeny* on devices without a hover, e.g tablets and phones?

Comment: The tapping on the button, somehow simulates the hover. Tried it on some Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let us solve the problem step by step. At first come to the point, where you've said:

> tried either static (in px), or using percentage with no luck.

This is because, the problem was caused by: `transition: linear 0.2s;` in your `nmbutoni` class. When you remove that line and set the padding of `nmbutoni` and `meny` to some static(px) value, it will work partially. Look at the snippet below:

```css
.meny {
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float: none;
}

.nmbutoni {
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 100%;
  float: none;
}



/* Smartphones (portrait & landscape) */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .nmbutoni {
    padding: 18% 37%;
  }
  footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #282828 !important;
    width: 70% !important;
    color: white;
  }
  #googleMap {
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
  }
}


/* position of main menu */

.nenmeny {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* dropdown content (default hidden) */

.nenmeny-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  min-width: 155px;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside dropdown menu*/

.nenmeny-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 7% 9%;
  /*12px 16px*/
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Hover color change */

.nenmeny-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}


/* Displaying content on hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nenmeny-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Bgcolor change on dropdown hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nmbutoni {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFB849;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="meny active">Ballina</a>
<a href="lajme.html" class="meny">Lajme</a>
<a href="ekipet.html" class="meny">Ekipet</a>
<a href="sponsor.html" class="meny">Sponzorët</a>
<div class="nenmeny">
  <button class="nmbutoni">Për ne</button>
  <div class="nenmeny-content">
    <a href="rrethparkour.html">Sporti Parkour</a>
    <a href="historia.html">Historia jonë</a>
    <a href="kontakti.html">Kontakti</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you look carefully, the button is not perfectly in line with other links, still the button's size is slightly bigger on top. This is because `button` is a form element. So, it works differently than other elements. So, it's a problem here.

And, another problem is when you use percentage, then they are working differntly, because **`%` is relative to the parent element** and the parent of `nmbutoni` and `meny` aren't same  in this case.

So, to solve the first problem we will simply replace the `<button>` with the `<a>` tag as suggested by [Nandita Arora Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4990572/nandita-arora-sharma) too in her answer, so that all the links become similar so no issue of having form elements.

And, for solving the 2nd problem, we will not use `%` rather use **`vw` which is relative to 1% of the width of the viewport i.e. the browser window size**.

So, here's the complete solution with cleaner code:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.meny {
  background-color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1vw;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nmbutoni {
  background-color: #282828;
  color: white;
  padding: 1vw;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nenmeny {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nenmeny-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 155px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.nenmeny-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.nenmeny-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd
}

.nenmeny:hover .nenmeny-content {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.nenmeny:hover .nmbutoni {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFB849;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="meny">Ballina</a>
<a href="lajme.html" class="meny">Lajme</a>
<a href="ekipet.html" class="meny">Ekipet</a>
<a href="sponsor.html" class="meny">Sponzorët</a>
<div class="nenmeny">
  <a class="nmbutoni">Për ne</a>
  <div class="nenmeny-content">
    <a href="rrethparkour.html">Sporti Parkour</a>
    <a href="historia.html">Historia jonë</a>
    <a href="kontakti.html">Kontakti</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This code looks neat! Thanks for explaining.
I've stumbled another problem. I've set `padding: 1vw;` due to size and now the content of dropdown is not attached to the "Per ne" therefore there's a little bit of space between the dropdown button and content, and if you don't slide cursor fast into content, it disappears. Any idea how to attach content of dropdown to the button itself?

Comment: You're right, this problem must occur as you also had to change the value of `margin-top` in `.nenmeny:hover .nenmeny-content { }` to also `1vw` or whatever you set in the padding.

Comment: It is OK now. Your answer is accepted as a solution. One more thing: If I add `padding-left: 2%` to the `.meny` class, why the `text-align:center;` does not have effect? The button expands, but text is floating right?

Comment: Because, this is the desired behavior, the idea of providing padding is to create some extra space inside the border, so it is actually in center but starting from where the padding ends. So, if you want to center your text by this way, you have to add the equal amount of padding in right side as well. I mean, for your case, also add: `padding-right: 2%;`

Answer (score 1):

Changed button tag to anchor in the dropdown. Added meny class to the dropdown container.
Also added `left: 0` on `nenmeny-content` div

```css
.meny {
 background-color: #282828;
 border-radius: 10%;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 float: none;
}

.nmbutoni {
 background-color: #282828;
 border-radius: 10%;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 float: none;
 transition: linear 0.2s;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .nmbutoni {
    padding: 14% 15%;
  }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait & landscape) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
 .nmbutoni {
 padding: 18% 37%;
 }
 footer {
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #282828 !important;
 width: 70% !important;
 color: white;
 }
 #googleMap {
  width: 500px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
 }
}

/* position of main menu */

.nenmeny {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

/* dropdown content (default hidden) */

.nenmeny-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 min-width: 155px;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 0;
}

/* Links inside dropdown menu*/

.nenmeny-content a {
 color: black;
 padding: 7% 9%;
 /*12px 16px*/
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
}

/* Hover color change */

.nenmeny-content a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd
}

/* Displaying content on hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nenmeny-content {
 display: block;

}

/* Bgcolor change on dropdown hover */

.nenmeny:hover .nmbutoni {
 background-color: black;
 color: #FFB849;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="meny active">Ballina</a>
<a href="lajme.html" class="meny">Lajme</a>
<a href="ekipet.html" class="meny">Ekipet</a>
<a href="sponsor.html" class="meny">Sponzorët</a>
<div class="nenmeny meny">
 <a class="nmbutoni">Përne</a>
 <div class="nenmeny-content">
  <a href="rrethparkour.html">Sporti Parkour</a>
  <a href="historia.html">Historia jonë</a>
  <a href="kontakti.html">Kontakti</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the proper tool for the job.  Note, styling the select to look identical across all browsers/devices is very challenging. You might try a UI library such as Google's [MDC-Web select](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-select).

#### `<select>`

> The HTML  element represents a control that provides a menu of
>   options:

```html
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="text"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'text'-->
  <option value="first">First Value</option> 
  <option value="second" selected>Second Value</option>
  <option value="third">Third Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A `select` element for navigation is very rarely the right tool for the job and would require JavaScript to perform the navigation.

Comment: `<a>` is not a valid child of `<option>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option and just plain doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/g9wpyrmb/2/

Comment: could do `select onchange="self.location.href = '#' + options[selectedIndex].value;` for anchor functionality or `select onchange="window.location.href = '#' + options[selectedIndex].value;